# Displaying surf actual size?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Is there a way to display `surf` in its actual size and aspect ratio? I've been looking in the web but couldn't find anything which worked. I'm also quite new to MATLAB.

Here is my code:

```
rpos1 = 0;  % image row vector pos counter
rpos2 = 0; % existing image vector pos counter
rpos3 = 0; % avg vector pos counter
prompt = {'Image location:','Lowest image #:','Highest image #:','Row of interest:','Background noise reduction:'};
dlg_title = 'Input';
num_lines = 1;
def = {'C:\Users\Moz\Desktop\Hyperspecdata\images','300','390','700','100'};
answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,def);
directory = (answer{1}); 
x1 = str2num(answer{2});
x2 = x1;
y1 = str2num(answer{3});
y2 = y1-1;
z = str2num(answer{4});
v = str2num(answer{5});
 finalslice = zeros(1,1312); % create matrix (imagecount x 1312)

%INSERT SLICES WITH 1 GAP%
for k = x1 : y1 
    baseFileName = sprintf('image0000000%03d.pgm',k);
    fullFileName = fullfile(directory, baseFileName); %fullfile(folder, baseFileName);
    A = imread(fullFileName);
    A = floor(A./16); % transform back to 12 bit
    B = A-v; % remove background noise 
    rpos1 = rpos1+1; % jump to next row
    thisline = B(z,:); % desired row in images
    finalslice(rpos1,:) = thisline; % add row vector
    rpos1 = rpos1+1; % jump to next row
    emptyline = zeros(1,1312); % create empty row vector
    finalslice(rpos1,:) = emptyline; % insert empty row vector
end

%INSERT AVERAGES INTO GAPS%
for k = x2 : y2 
    rpos2 = rpos2+1; % find first existing vector
    line1 = finalslice(rpos2,:); 
    rpos2 = rpos2+2; % find second existing vector
    line2 = finalslice(rpos2,:);
    avgline1 = (line1 + line2)/2; % average both
    rpos3 = rpos3+2;
    finalslice(rpos3,:) = avgline1; % insert average vector
    rpos2 = rpos2-1; % jump back to second existing vector
end

figure(1)
h = surf(finalslice,'EdgeColor','none','LineStyle','none','FaceLighting','phong');
colormap('jet');
view(2)
```

I'm loading a bunch of images and taking slices at a specific points and stitching them together. The output doesn't display the actual size and aspect ratio.

Comment: What is your expected result and what are you getting instead?

Comment: I',m expecting a 182x1312 output but getting a streched one. its not showing its actual size. I would like to see a 182x1312 surface plot

Comment: Streched one? Actual size? Do you mean `axis equal`? Or `axis vis3d`?

Comment: There is no "actual size". A "surf" is a virtual 3d object, described by abstract coordinates without units. Please explain more precisely what it is you want to achieve. And, while it is generally good to include code, your code is very long, unexplained, hard to understand, and can not be run by a reader of your question. To get a good answer, you need to post a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, didnt explain the problem right. I was looking for `daspect()`. which solved the problem.

Comment: Nice to know! I guess you can post the solution in the answer section below and accept it for future readers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

Added `daspect()`

```
o = max(max(finalslice)); 
[m n] = size(finalslice); 
figure(1) h = surf(finalslice,'EdgeColor','none','LineStyle','none','FaceLighting','phong'); colormap('jet'); 
view(2) 
daspect([m n o]);
```